# How to use bind function of groupie library in java?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am trying to show a list of user in recyclerView and trying to connect the textview layout in bind method in groupie library and i don't know how to link the id of layout to recyclerview viewHolder? and also how to use picasso library in viewholder?

```
private void fetchUser(){
DatabaseReference fireBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/userList");
     fireBaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             GroupAdapter groupA = new GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>();
             for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                 Log.d("userList",snapshot.toString());
                 Users string = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                 groupA.add(new UserItem());


             }
             recyclerView.setAdapter(groupA);


         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });

}
}
    class  UserItem extends Item<ViewHolder>{



//    public  UserItem(Users users){

//    }
 private   Users users = new Users();

@Override
public void bind(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

     viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_from_user_list);
     viewHolder.

     Picasso.get().load(users.getUri()).into(viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_photo_from_user_list));




}

@Override
public int getLayout() {
     return R.layout.user_list_view_layout;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groupie abstracts away the complexity of multiple item view types. Each Item declares a view layout id, and gets a callback to bind the inflated layout. That's all you need; you can add your new item directly to a GroupAdapter and call it a day.

**Item with Kotlin**
The Item class gives you simple callbacks to bind your model object to the generated fields. Because of Kotlin Android extensions, there's no need to write a view holder.**

```
class SongItem(private val song: Song) : Item() {

override fun getLayout() = R.layout.song

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.title.text = song.title
    viewHolder.artist.text = song.artist
    }
}
```

**Item with data binding:**
The Item class gives you simple callbacks to bind your model object to the generated binding. Because of data binding, there's no need to write a view holder.

If you're converting existing ViewHolders, you can reference any named views (e.g. R.id.title) directly from the binding instead.

```
@Override public void bind(SongBinding binding, int position) {
    binding.title.setText(song.getTitle());
}
```

or you can do this way

```
 @Override
public void bind(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    circleImageView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageViewForLatestMessage);
    userMessage = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    userName = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView41);
    userName.setText(name);
    userMessage.setText(messages);
```

You can also mix and match BindableItem and other Items in the adapter, so you can leave legacy viewholders as they are by making an Item.

For more information visit [Groupie Library](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie)

Comment: Can you please explain? What is title and artist?

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE title and text is the item view of View holder class.

Comment: So you don't need findViewById? I can't find a java example implementation of it

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE I updated the answer. You can find references by viewholder like recyclerview.